# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I'm working in a project in which we need to write down some data into a SQL Server database.

This is my connection string:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="conexionServidorHotel" 
             connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-QG08OQQ\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Script_RESORTSUNED;Integrated Security=True;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And this is the code I'm currently using:

```
using Entidades;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AccesoDatos
{
    public class HotelAD
    {
        private string cadenaConexion;

        public HotelAD()
        {
            cadenaConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionServidorHotel"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public bool RegistrarHotel(Hotel NuevoHotel)
        {
            bool hotelregistrado = false;

            try
            {
                SqlConnection conexion;
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();

                using (conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion))
                {
                    string instruccion = " Insert   Into    Hotel (IdHotel,     Nombre,     Direccion,      Estado,     Telefono)" +
                                " Values    (@IdHotel,      @Nombre,        @Direccion,     @Estado,     @Telefono)";
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    comando.CommandText = instruccion;
                    comando.Connection = conexion;
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdHotel", NuevoHotel.IDHotel);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", NuevoHotel.NombreHotel);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", NuevoHotel.DireccionHotel);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", NuevoHotel.StatusHotel);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", NuevoHotel.TelefonoHotel);
                    conexion.Open();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Aqui voy bien 7");
                    hotelregistrado = comando.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;

                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No puedo escribir en la base de datos");
            }

            return hotelregistrado;
        }
    }
}
```

My project is in Spanish. That is why variable names are in Spanish. When I run my code, and I input the data for the Hotel object, it works fine until `conexion.Open()`.

Something tells me there's something wrong with that command but not sure what. Its throwing me the error:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll

I reviewed the connection string and it looks good to me. The SQL Server file I have is not in the same directory as the C# solution but one directory before. I'm not sure if using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` could be affecting too.

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Comment: Can you print the exception Message, it probably tells you more than just InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @KlausGütter the full message says Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll . That's all what it says.

Comment: What I meant: `catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }`

Comment: Has the field IDHotel the Identity attribute set to true in your database table?

Comment: It's a bit weird to open Connection so late in the game, Usually the pattern is: `using(Connection...) { con.Open(); using(SQLCommand(sql, con){...}` but agree with above, you need to print full exception.

Comment: @siggemannen nothing wrong with deferring open

Comment: @Kabir this *will not* change the open failing, but: have you considered Dapper? It makes this literally two lines - and one of those lines is `using var connection = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion))`

Comment: @Kabir it's impossible to guess what's wrong without the actual error. What you posted is the type of the exception only. Post the *full* exception text, returned by `Exception.ToString()`. You can write `Console.WriteLine(ex)` too. `WriteLine` will call `Exception.ToString()` itself. The full text contains possible inner exceptions and additional details, including error codes that may not appear in `Exception.Message`

Comment: `The SQL Server file I have is not in the same directory as the C# solution but one directory before` which file is this? The database file? That should be in your SQL Server install directory unless you are using LocalDB which you don't appear to be from the connection string.

Comment: @KlausGütter I modified the code, putting conexion.Open() at the beginning and the message I got is Instance failure.

Comment: @Steve the IDHotel attribute is an int attribute. It's set that way in the C# code and in the SQL database.

Comment: Open SQL Server Management Studio, go to your db and tables. Right click on the Hotel table and choose "design". Click on the IDHotel field and loop at the Column Properties window. Is the line "Identity Specification" set to Yes?

Comment: "the message I got is Instance failure" - really nothing more specific?

Answer (score 0):

If it fails at `Open()`, there are two options:

1. The connection string `cadenaConexion` is invalid (which we can't see); recheck it, or try using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`; recheck the server, database, auth, certs if needed, etc
2. The connection string is valid, but you can't reach the server; DNS, firewall, routing; or simply the server is stopped